# Database syncup

Tags: php, mysql

We have one web server and Mysql server is in US region. We are planning to move the website to India. But all admin operation will be in US region only. So what is the best way to do the  database connect to the US region database. or Can we create one more mysql server in India and is there a way to sync the data to US Db server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> 1) you can use remote database server as mysql support to connect remote database.
>
> 2) if you want to keep **US** database and want to sync from india server then use **mysql replication**
>
> make us database server as master database which do database write operation.
>
> create 1 or more slave which actually database reading openration

more details on database replication ***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html***

Comment: If i write to remote server (US Master) what could be the latency to sync up and we already have Master slave configuration in US region...But read from US Slave From india what could be the latency...From our back end operation (US) also write to master so if there a latency then there is a chance of auto increment value conflict...sorry correct me if i am wrong...